# Asynctask within service() or download manager to download the files from server

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service, android-download-manager

I have a listView and and click of each row I have to download an mp3 file. I'm confused between AsyncTask within service() and build in DownloadManager (above API 9).

However because you handle each call to `onStartCommand()` yourself, you can perform multiple requests simultaneously. That's not what this example does, but if that's what you want, then you can create a new thread for each request and run them right away (instead of waiting for the previous request to finish).

From above line from docs I am thinking to create new instance of `AsyncTask` in the `onStartCommand` method, so each file will be downloaded as a separate task, but while searching I came across DownloadManagerr. I found very little information about it in the documentation.

I'm having doubts about DownloadManager. Does it is work like IntentService? Someone please guide me what to use (AsyncTask within service() or DownloadManager) and please clear up the above doubts.

Comment: You need to change executor in AsyncTask if you want parallel downloads, otherwise you'll end up with multiple AsyncTasks that execute serially (the default).

Comment: Hey @gil thanks for reply. Sorry ,I am not getting "change executer in asynk task"

Comment: @gil can you please provide link or some code snipet for above scenario . thanks

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR

Comment: Then you execute the tasks with executeOnExecutor()

Comment: I suggest you to write your code using Service and Asynctask. Here is example ready version:  http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Network/FileDownloadService.htm

Answer (score 0):

**Asynktask within service()**

Implementing this code is much easier because you just create a service and start it by calling

```
startService(my_service);
```

But as begin service it can be stop by android when low on memory (your task will fail) It can be manually shutdown By user by going to setting and third It can be shut off if the phone is switched off you cannot resume your task after boot

**DownloadManager**

With DownloadManager you have to setup a BrodcastReceiver *ACTION_NOTIFICATION_CLICKED* but you get more control over your download as this API was solely developed for downloading purpose

Pros:

1. Download Can be restart after your cell has rebooted.
2. Can limit use over mobile networks (force wifi download only).

Comment: So what is better option ?